# Como devolver la longitud de un array usando una function?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std ; 


int arrayLen(int *x ){

    return (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x)) ; 
}

int main (){

    int array[55] , result = 0 ; 

    result = arrayLen(array);
    cout<<result;
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podes explicar un poco mas que problema tenes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes conocer la longitud de un array a partir de un puntero a los datos, ya que el puntero tan sólo contiene la dirección en que comienza el array, pero no dónde finaliza.

Cuando haces `sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x)` lo que estás calculando no es la relación de tamaños entre el array y uno de sus elementos, sino entre el puntero y el elemento al que apunta. El tamaño de un puntero es siempre el mismo, tanto si apunta a un array de 100 enteros como si apunta a un solo entero, ya que el tamaño de un puntero no es más que el tamaño de las direcciones de memoria en la arquitectura en la que trabajes. Por ejemplo, en arquitecturas de 64 bits, un puntero ocupa 64 bits, es decir, 8 bytes. En ese caso tu división dará 8/4 = 2 (asumiendo que el entero son 32 bits), sin importar cuántos elementos tenga el array.

Por esta misma razón las cadenas en C usan un *centinela* o *terminador*, que es un byte con un valor especial que denota que es el último elemento. Funciones como `strlen()` reciben un puntero a dónde comienza la cadena, pero para saber dónde acaba han de recorrerla hasta encontrar el *centinela* (que en el caso del C es un byte con valor cero).

Por esta misma razón las funciones que trabajan con *buffers*, como `fread()`, necesitan dos parámetros relacionados con el mismo: un puntero a su inicio, y un entero que le indique su tamaño.

Quizás te resulte más cómodo juntar ambos datos en una estructura, que contendría por tanto un puntero a los datos y un entero con su tamaño, y pasar esa estructura como único parámetro, aunque eso complicaría un poco el acceso a los elementos del array. En cualquier caso, le estarías pasando también (de otra forma) ambos datos a la función. No hay otra forma.